# Error: "non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a problem while compiling a simple program. I started using Swing library two days ago, so i'm not good enough yet.
The error is: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context", referred to "WindowsEraser listener = new WindowsEraser();".
What is the problem?

```
public class prog9{
    public class WindowEraser extends WindowAdapter{
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame with buttons");
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("I'm a Window");
        frame.add(label);   
        WindowEraser listener = new WindowEraser();
        frame.addWindowListener(listener);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate WindowEraser() in this way too:

```
WindowEraser listener = new prog9().new WindowEraser();
```

Answer (score 0):

make `WindowEraser` static otherwise `main()` can't access it

Answer (score -1):

You can't refer to non static fields/classes/methods from static context (because static context can be initialized earlier and then there will be no reference to non-static entity)

You should make WindowEraser class static:

```
 public static class WindowEraser extends WindowAdapter
```

Comment: Ok, that works. That was an oversight. My bad.